# Mac OS X defaults UI

Tags: macos

So, there's this command line thing `defaults` that lets you change the default settings for certain programs that register their defaults using it, you can access through the terminal, which is sweet, but I'd like a UI for it.

Anyone have one?

Comment: Not comprehensive, but [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) includes a lot of hidden settings for various programs accessible through `defaults`.

Answer (score 2):

You want Property List Editor, which is part of Apple's developer tools. You can install them from your 10.6 DVD. You might also be interested in Secrets, which is a prefpane that gives you access to many of the common edits people do with defaults write. There are also a few 3rd party apps that do the same thing as Apple's application, although I recommend Apple's.

http://secrets.blacktree.com/